# Get value from Map of Map of Map without null pointer exception

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have

```
Map<String, Map<String, Time>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Time>>();
Time t = map.get("key1").get("key2");
```

Is there any way using lambda to get the value of Time t without NullPointerException in between.
So if key1 return null value then t should null and code should not throw null pointer

Comment: Can the result, `Time t` be null in the end?

Comment: @Tiulum yes it can be

Answer (score 10):

Use `getOrDefault` introduced in Java8 with your key and `Collections.emptyMap()` as the default value. Here's how it looks.

```
Time t = map.getOrDefault("key1", Collections.emptyMap()).get("key2");
```

Comment: ..but `Time t` could still be `null`, so hopefully, OP would be checking that to avoid a `NullPointerException` further.

Comment: yes, that involves an explicit null check. Moreover, OP needs it to be `null` too as per his problem statement.

Comment: `Map.of()` is available in Java9, but it seems that the OP uses Java8. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of--

Comment: @Naman of course, when the OP has a reasonable default value, they can use `map.getOrDefault("key1", Collections.emptyMap()).getOrDefault("key2", fallback)`

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8

```
Time t = Optional.ofNullable(map.get("key1"))
            .map(m -> m.get("key2"))
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: You don't need optionals here, they are not a substitute for null checks.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala why not?

Comment: I have explained the reason in my previous comment and that leaves your second comment obsolete.

Comment: You've just **stated** it, not explained

Comment: Well, optionals are hideous when it comes to performance. Every time when you want to get the value, you have to unwrap the optional.